# Laravel 4: when using Config::set to change auth.model then Auth::user() not work

Tags: authentication, laravel, config

My laravel project has two login system. 
1) Using user_name and Password 
2) Using secret code

my 1st login system work properly. because auth.model has 'User' model.
so I use 'Config::set' in 'tempSing' method to obtain 2nd login as bellow.

```
Config::set('auth.model', 'TempUser') 
Config::set('auth.table', 'temp_user')
```

After that code I use bellow code

```
$user= TempUser::where('secret_code','=',Input::get('code'))->first();
Auth::login($user,true);
if(Auth::check())
 return Redirect::route('getTemp');
```

then that code work properly and redirect to the 'getTemp' and after routing it make 'temp.php'. but their include

```
if(Auth::check())
```

so my problem is above logic not become true. that problem is occurred when using 'Config::set' but I Configured 'auth.model' and 'auth.table' manualy in 'auth.php' not happen any error. Please help me.

Comment: I would assume Laravel initializes the `Auth` service once when the application is started, so later edits to configuration don't affect it anymore. A solution would be to initialize an instance yourself, and use that.

Comment: Hey Martti  thanks for your help. Your comment up as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Posted as an answer, happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume Laravel initializes the `Auth` service once when the application is started, so later edits to configuration don't affect it anymore. A solution would be to initialize an instance yourself, and use that.

Comment: Sorry to wake up this question, but do you know in any way this can be achieved (if it is achievable)?