# Dynemically timezone is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, timezone

I have set dynamic time zone in my app but it's showing wrong result. Here is my code

```
    $timezone = [
        'asia_calcutta_time' => 'Asia/Calcutta',
        'europe_madrid_time' => 'Europe/Madrid',
        'us_eastern_time' => 'US/Eastern'
    ];
    foreach ($timezone as $timeKey => $timeValue) {
        \Config::set('app.timezone', $timeValue);
        echo $timeValue . "<br>Seted time zone => ";
        echo \Config::get('app.timezone') . "<br>";

        print_r(new \DateTime('now'));
        print_r("<br>");
    }
```

My output

```
Asia/Calcutta
Seted time zone => Asia/Calcutta
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-07-05 14:51:41.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta )
Europe/Madrid
Seted time zone => Europe/Madrid
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-07-05 14:51:41.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta )
US/Eastern
Seted time zone => US/Eastern
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-07-05 14:51:41.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta )
```

Here i have set timezone using `\Config::set('app.timezone', $timeValue);` and after when i get timezone using `\Config::get('app.timezone');` then it's show perfect but when i print datetime object then it's show different timezone so how can i solve this problem . i have also try after clear cache, clear compiled, clear config, clear route, clear view but it's not showing proper result

Comment: I think I personally have encountered issues with using `Config::set()` sometimes ago. The first time the function is called is the last time it worked. Have you tried a hack for example setting it just once and see if it print the right result? Also you may want to run a little test with: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');`

Comment: Thanks, I have already try with `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');`  and it's working but i want to change timezone through the laravel way not core php way

Answer (score 0):

I personally have encountered issues with using Config::set() sometimes ago. The first time the function is called is the last time it worked. You can see a ref here: [Way to use Config::set() twice in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42251056/5704410)

You can have it as this using new Instance of `DateTimeZone` in DateTime instead of using `Config::set()`:

```
foreach ($timezone as $timeKey => $timeValue) {
    echo $timeValue . "<br>Seted time zone => ".$timeValue;
    print_r(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone($timeValue)));
    print_r("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to change timezone for whole environment  not with particular date, same as working like `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');` function through the config variable changes . and also one of my question is config timezone changed but why timezone not changed in datetime object ?